# cmake: How can I import a target from a sub-directory to a higher level?

Tags: cmake

Given a recusive build structure. How can I import a target from a lower level to a higher level?
Here is a simplified example:

toplevel *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_subdirectory(sub1)
```

*sub1/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_subdirectory(subdir)
add_executable(foo EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
  foo.cpp)

add_custom_target(both)
add_dependencies(both DEPENDS foo bar)
```

*sub1/subdir/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_executable(bar EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
  bar.cpp)
```

At the toplevel all targets are visible:

- make foo   - builds foo
- make bar   - builds bar
- make both  - builds foo & bar

At the bottom level (sub1/subdir) only *bar* is visible:

- make bar   - builds bar

At the middle level only *foo* is visible as a target:

- make foo   - builds foo
- make both  - builds foo & bar

*make help* shows:

```
The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:
... all (the default if no target is provided)
... clean
... depend
... edit_cache
... rebuild_cache
... both
... foo
... foo.o
... foo.i
... foo.s
```

**How can I add *bar* to this list without moving the build instructions up a level?**

Comment: Isn't it possible to use CMake's buildsystem-agnostic commands to build specific targets? `cmake --build <build_dir> --target <target>...`? [docs for `--target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-t). If so, is there a reason you don't use that way of invoking the build that way?

Comment: It was a long time ago now but I think the point of this question was to have to have the "make both" target to work and for this target to be listed via "make help".

Answer (score -1):

If I change

```
add_dependencies(both DEPENDS foo bar)
```

to

```
add_dependencies(both foo bar)
```

I get the following response to *make help* in the top folder:

```
The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:
... all (the default if no target is provided)
... clean
... depend
... edit_cache
... rebuild_cache
... both
... foo
... bar
```

Have a look at the documentation:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_dependencies.html

Comment: All targets are available at the toplevel already. Its the next directory down I'm interested in. Removing the DEPENDS makes no difference though it is unnecessary.

Comment: You're correct.
Can you elaborate a little bit about your use case and why it isn't enough to call 'make bar' from the top folder?

Comment: It was originally a migration thing. The workflow before switching to cmake was to work within the tree containing a subproject and build targets from there. This is of course old style "in source tree" build thinking but it should still be possible in principle. It should also be possible from a sub-directory of the build tree in an out of source build.

Comment: I've look at my other CMake project and they all seem to work in the same way (not the way you want it to work).
What you can do is to call `make -C .. bar` from the subdirectory

Comment: That's actually a better answer than your main answer.
I've never used nor noticed the -C option of make. Not a bad idea. It works but doesn't save you much typing. At least it can be generalised if you replace .. with an environment variable pointing to the top of the build tree.
It still doesn't answer the question from the cmake side though.